# Canvas: create semi-transparent overlay over entire canvas except one window

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a rectangular canvas with an image painted on it. As the user moves the cursor over the canvas, I'd like to make the canvas semitransparent *except* for a small rectangle around the cursor, which I'd like to retain the underlying image content in full opacity.

So my question in brief is how to "mute" the canvas except for a small rectangle.

My first thought was to create a semitransparent overlay over the entire canvas, then just paint the rectangular region that should be full opacity again, but this makes the background disappear while I want to retain it at 0.2 opacity:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = elem.getContext('2d');

elem.width = 400;
elem.height = 300;

ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0000';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, elem.width, elem.height);

elem.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, elem.width, elem.height);
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  var d = 30;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0000';
  ctx.fillRect(x-d, y-d, d*2, d*2);
})
```

```html
<canvas/>
```

Does anyone know the most performant way to mute the background to 0.2 opacity while retaining the rectangle around the cursor at full opacity? Any pointers would be super helpful!

Comment: Ah, I just had a vision of another canvas lying on top of this one that could serve to make only the area near the cursor opaque...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the two canvas method:

```js
var elemA = document.querySelector('#a');
var elemB = document.querySelector('#b');
var ctx = elemA.getContext('2d');
var bctx = elemB.getContext('2d');

elemA.width = elemB.width = 400;
elemA.height = elemB.height = 300;

ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0000';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, elemA.width, elemA.height);
elemB.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  bctx.clearRect(0, 0, elemB.width, elemB.height);
  
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  var x0 = x-10;
  var x1 = x+10;
  var y0 = y-10;
  var y1 = y+10;

  // draw boxes; origin is top left
  bctx.globalAlpha = 0.8;
  bctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
  bctx.fillRect(0, 0, elemA.width, y0); // top
  bctx.fillRect(0, y0, x0, elemB.height+20); // left
  bctx.fillRect(x0, y1, elemB.width+20, elemB.height); // bottom
  bctx.fillRect(x1, y0, elemA.width, y1-y0); // right
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

#c {
  position: relative;
}

#a, #b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#b {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id='c'>
  <canvas id='a'></canvas>
  <canvas id='b'></canvas>
</div>
```